# Textarea text blur on animate method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

how I resolve this issue on my textarea?
I'm using jquery mobile.
when i animate the textarea increasing the height I got the text blurred.

my textarea:

```
<button class="divArea"><textarea rows="2" class="description" readonly></textarea></button>
```

I animate textarea like this:

```
$(".description").animate({ height: '250px' }, 500);
```

I have also tried to enlarge textarea like this:

```
$(".description").attr('rows', '10');
```

but does not work(the textarea maintein its initial rows number of 2).

Comment: When are you animating? On click, on load?

Comment: $(".divArea").on("tap", function(){

Comment: I'm animating on tap of the cover button, because I was using disabled textarea, now I'm using readonly so the click could possibly work, but I'm gonna let the button over for the click effect; if the button is not the problem.

Comment: It doesn't blur on a desktop fiddle (on click), but I suppose that's not much help.

Comment: did you try `.blur()` after animation?

Comment: Maybe it's a conflict with jquery mobile or other css.
Now I try the .blur()

Comment: .blur() method does not solve the problem, its also 'readonly' textarea so seems to do nothing; oh and the blur comes during the animation, at like half of animation the text blur itself

Comment: By "blur"... Do you mean that the textarea content gets fuzzy... Or that the textarea element itself loses focus? (most comments above talk about the second one)

Comment: That the content get blurry/fuzzy, like the image I posted.
I discovered that if i uncheck via browser the .ui-btn { position: relative} it does not get blurry. How should I proper remove this css jquery mobile property via jquery or css? Or there's something like position: none?

Comment: Ok " position: initial !important; " on css for my divArea (.ui-btn) solved the problem.
Still don't understand why the text gone blurry on position: relative.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution with pure `JavaScript` https://jsfiddle.net/L7nkswuv/1/

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('description')[0].setAttribute('rows', '10');
```

```html
<button class="divArea"><textarea rows="2" class="description" readonly></textarea></button>
```

Use pure `JavaScript`.

Using **`jQuery` > 1.6**

`$(".description").prop('rows', '10');`

Using **`jQuery` < 1.6**
`$(".description").attr('rows', '10');`

Hope this will help you.